# Shopping cart page, update quantity by ajax

Tags: magento2, ajax, shopping-cart, qty

**Issue:-**

Is there a ready solution to update shopping cart page by ajax `url/checkout/cart/?`

I found similar questions but there is no working solution, but as for me, it's very useful feature and should be some implementation.

I not ready to provide a code, trying to implement this solution for my needs 
`https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187226/ajax-cart-validation-on-change-qty?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did this with such JS, if need ready solution ping me. not pretty cool, but was need to save compatibility with non default themes

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
            var form = $('form#form-validate');
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                showLoader: true,
                success: function (res) {
                    var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                    var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                    var sections = ['cart'];

                    $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

                    // The mini cart reloading
                    customerData.reload(sections, true);

                    // The totals summary block reloading
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    console.log(err.Message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Maxim R. Please elaborate the answer. We are trying to achieve this.

Comment: While doing this change, summary action is not updating properly.

Comment: i have added this for ajax qty update but i am trying to get subtotal customerData.get('cart')._latestValue.subtotalAmount is is gving me old subtotal , How to get updated total here