# How to auto update Subtotal, Total in cart when I update product qty?

Tags: magento2, cart, magento-2.1.7

As when I change product **qty** in shopping cart,  `total` and `subtotal` value must change without clicking on `Update Shoping item` button

Comment: On clicking Update Shopping cart - still it is not working ?

Comment: Its working as i need to As when i change product qty in shopping cart total and subtotal value must change without clicking update Aditya Shah

Comment: ohh you need an AJAX call

Comment: Yeah how can i get it..

Comment: There are multiple solution out there.. which are already answered :) so i can provide the links

Comment: yeah provide me its needfull for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84282/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-trilok-kumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Magento 2 - Reload totals cart after ajax change quantity**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002976/magento-2-reload-totals-cart-after-ajax-change-quantity?rq=1
2. [Shopping cart page, update quantity by ajax](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224363/shopping-cart-page-update-quantity-by-ajax)
3. [How to update cart qty using ajax Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235040/how-to-update-cart-qty-using-ajax-magento-2)
4. https://inchoo.net/magento-2/improve-usability-magento-2-add-cart-process/

Once the ajax process is complete, we can **trigger** scroll event to scroll on top of the page and as soon as `mini-cart` get’s updated we can then trigger `mini-cart` UI dialog to open and show us the complete experience and what `mini-cart` is actually offering to us (either to go to the cart, go to the checkout or continue shopping).

Answer (score 3):

Just run the following js code -

```
require(
[
   'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
   'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'
],
function(
   quote,
   totalsDefaultProvider
) {
     totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
  }
);
```